# Two vertical collection views and a label between them to scroll all at once as one element

Tags: ios, swift

I have two collection views with data loaded from an API. the data varies that means that the heights of each of the collection views should be varying. I have tried putting all of them  ( 2 collection views and a label between them ) inside a scroll view but that doesn't work because I cannot tell the size of the contents before the data is loaded. How can I do this?

Comment: Do the collectionView cells have fixed height?

Comment: No, they do not, both are dynamic depending on the content from an API. thus they have varying heights

Comment: If the cells had same height it might have been simpler. So, a possible solution: Subclass `UICollectionView` (and use them in your ScrollView). Add it a closure: var contentSizeDiChange: ((CGSize) -> Void)? Override only the `didSet` of `contentSize`, and when called do `self.bounds = CGRect(point: CGPointZero, size: contentSize); self.contentSizeDidChange?(self.contentSize)`. On the View having the scrollView, implement the collectionView.contentSizeDidChange = { (newContentSize) in //Recalculate the correct contentSize of the scrollview and set it}`

Comment: Sorry, actually the cells are the same height for each of the collection views. the first has a cell height of 160 the other 180

Comment: That's simpler, and do you know in advance how many cells in width can fit? In other words, can you guess the height of the collectionView it will have after UI load? When you receive the info of from your backend, once you know the height of the collectionView, change its frame to it.

Comment: No, I cannot guess sadly.. they can be 10, 20, 30

Answer (score 0):

For many reasons, this is should not be the layout of choice for you in this situation. First, the collection views cannot determine their own size based on the size of their content, because they are in fact scroll views – and it would be weird for a scroll view to always scale to the size of its content, it would never scroll at all if it did. Second, as each of the collection views is a scroll view, you would have a hierarchy of scroll views which is hard to handle for the user, let alone the developer.

What I suggest instead is to use a single UICollectionView with multiple sections. You can also implement your own UICollectionViewLayout to suit your needs.

Comment: Then where should I place my labels? On the collection view header? I have tried that but I get an error that views cannot be placed on repeating content yet it is on the header

Comment: They can also be a separate section